# Is it possible to compare the means of two variable rated by the same sample using t-test?

Tags: t-test

A group of people rate their ratings on product A and B simultaneously. The mean of the ratings for product A is 4.5 (ranging from 0 to 5). The mean for B is 4.3. In this case, can we use t-test to examine if these two scores are significantly different? In other words, is it a way to tell if the people like product A more than B, statistically? Is t-test appropriate? I just saw that some paper did so in an academic journal. Thanks!

Comment: You should use a *paired* t-test.  Some people might argue that this is illegitimate for ordinal data like ratings.  Using rating differences makes it a little more defensible, but the same people would still object.  That was debated in the mid-20th century in response to Lord, F. M. (1953). [On the Statistical Treatment of Football Numbers](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2005-07821-008). American Psychologist, 8(12), 750–751. https://doi.org/10.1037/h0063675  Lord argued that manipulations like those of the t-test *can* be valid for such data.

Comment: Thanks! The thing here is that the researchers were trying to compare means for Product A and B rated by the same people and conclude that this group of people on average prefer A than B. So, the scale itself is not of interest. It could be other continuous measure. I just wonder if it's legitimate to use t-test to do this kind of comparison. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you include a plot in the post? And, maybe you should be interested in measures of agreement, search this site.